# How to make a CSS Shimmer Effect on Image?

Tags: css, css-animations, linear-gradients, background-position

I have the following shimmer effect working very well when used on a `p` element but it doesn't work on any `div` nor an `img`. So, what modifications should I make to make sure the shimmer effect plays on any element.

The snippet is below

```css
 .shimmer {
      display: inline-block;
      color:grey;
      background: #acacac -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0, 0 0, from(#acacac), color-stop(0.5, #ffffff), to(#acacac));
      background-position: -50rem top; /*50px*/
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-background-size: 50rem 100%; /*50px*/
      font-size: 90px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
        0% {
            background-position: -50rem top; /*50px*/
        }
        70% {
            background-position: 12.5rem top; /*200px*/
        }
        100% {
            background-position: 12.5rem top; /*200px*/
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>
<p class="shimmer">Shimmering Text</p>

<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQxk.png" width=100 height=100 alt="Image Should Shimmer.Unfortunately not working "/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Howdy, would you mind adding a reproducible example to help visualize? You can use the snippet editor (the button with the `<>` icon on it on the question editor) from what I see at first glance it should work fine on most elements but not `img` however there's workarounds for all that.

Comment: Hi, but I want it to work specifically for img. Even if it won't work on div it is fine, but I really want it to work for img

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean now. So your text works as expected since you have the option to specify `background-clip: text` but with your image unfortunately it's not so clean and you're restricted to the box model of its parent container (eg; `border-box`, `content-box`, etc) but if your background will consistently stay white like the example I can show you how to mimic the same effect, is that all you're looking for? Or are you needing it to clip to the image contents shape? That's trickier.

Comment: Yes, I want the background to stay consistently white while the  shimmer runs over the image repeatedly. I don't want it to clip to the image contents shape. That's all I need. Thank you

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use mask

```css
.shimmer {
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(-60deg,#000 30%,#0005,#000 70%) right/300% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: shimmer 2.5s infinite;
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width:200px;
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  100% {-webkit-mask-position:left}
}
```

```html
<p class="shimmer">Shimmering Text</p>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQxk.png"class="shimmer" />
```