# Shimmer Effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code were I am trying to add a shimmer effect to an image. Here is the code:

```css
.shimmer {
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(-60deg,#000 30%,#0005,#000 70%) right/300% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: shimmer 2.5s infinite;
}

.bottomhalf{
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQxk.png");
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  100% {-webkit-mask-position:left}
}
```

```html
<div class="shimmer bottomhalf">
```

However, when I try to use the code, the image either appears very small in the top left or the image appears a bit shrunk but moved to the left side. Is there anyway to fix this or to have the shimmer affect only the "background-image" rather than the whole "bottomhalf"? Thank you!

The initial code came from [Make CSS Shimmer Effect Work an already loaded Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216941/make-css-shimmer-effect-work-an-already-loaded-image) and an updated code came from [How to add shimmer effect in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924716/how-to-add-shimmer-effect-in-css)

Comment: don't repeat the question, update the old one with more detail

Answer (score 3):

```css
.shimmer {
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(-60deg,#000 30%,#0005,#000 70%) right/300% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: shimmer 2.5s infinite;
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width:200px;
}

 @keyframes shimmer {
 100% {-webkit-mask-position:left}
}
```

```html
<p class="shimmer">Your Text</p>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"class="shimmer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
.shimmer {
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(-60deg,#000 30%,#0005,#000 70%) right/300% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: shimmer 2.5s infinite;
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width:200px;
}

 @keyframes shimmer {
 100% {-webkit-mask-position:left}
}

<p class="shimmer">Shimmering Word</p>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQxk.png"class="shimmer" />
```